# Hilbert space and the interval of special relativity?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, hilbert-space, metric-tensor

One requirement of the Hilbert space is that it is normed. Furthermore, in the case of special relativity, the norm has the following problematic requirements:

$$
||u||\geq 0 \\
||u||= 0 \implies u=0   
$$

This requirements are respected in 3d space with metric $ds^2=dx^2+dy^2+dz^2$.

However, in special relativity, the interval is given by

$$
ds^2=dx^2+dy^2+dz^2-dt^2
$$

In the case of a photon traveling at the speed of light, the interval is always zero, yet u could be (3,4,0,5) such that $3^2+4^2+0^2-5^2=0$. In this case $u\neq 0$, but $||u||=0$. In some cases, the norm is negative such as $u=(0,0,0,5)$.

Consequently, the space of functions whose inner product is the interval of special relativity does not form a Hilbert space.

How does one reconcile Hilbert space with special relativity? Or are Hilbert spaces only relevant for non-relativistic quantum mechanics?

Comment: The Hilbert space and Minkowski inner products are unrelated. An element of the Hilbert space represents the state of the whole physical system, not a 4-component vector. Quantum physics can be reconciled with special relativity using quantum field theory. QFT is (or at least can be) expressed in terms of operators on a Hilbert space, just like in non-relativistic quantum mechanics. Perturbative treatments of QFT sometimes obscure this basic fact, but any halfway-decent intro to QFT should at least make it clear for free fields, which is enough to address this question.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the physical explanation given above, I'd like to point out the mathematical difference. A Hilbert space is a complex vector space equipped with an inner product that is also complete. A Minkowski space is a real vector space equipped with a symmetric bilinear form. A symmetric bilinear form is not the same as an inner product, that's why the 'norm' can be negative in Minkowski space. In fact, an inner product is defined as a symmetric bilinear form that's positive definite.

Answer (score 1):

Analogously to [indefinite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-Riemannian_manifold) [metric tensors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor) ([bilinear form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_form)), famously used in [relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_relativity), one can introduce indefinite ([pre](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Pre-Hilbert_space)-)[Hilbert spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space) ${\cal H}$ with negative norm states.

This is e.g. done in the [BRST operator formulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BRST_quantization) of gauge theories in QFT with a Grassmann-odd self-adjoint BRST operator $\hat{Q}$ on an indefinite$^1$ (pre-)Hilbert spaces ${\cal H}$ that is nilpotent $$\hat{Q}^2~=~0.$$ The physical Hilbert space$^2$ 
$${\cal H}_{\rm phys}~:=~{\rm Ker}(\hat{Q})/{\rm Im}(\hat{Q})$$
is constructed such that the induced [sesquilinear form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sesquilinear_form) $$\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle:~ {\cal H}_{\rm phys}\times {\cal H}_{\rm phys}\to \mathbb{C}$$ in the physical sector is positive definite. (This is necessary in order for physical probabilities to be non-negative.)

--

$^1$ In fact the indefinite (pre-)Hilbert space sesquilinear form is typically a consequence of the indefinite metric of spacetime as the BRST formulations of relativistic theories are manifestly Lorentz-covariant. Moreover, the vector space is actually a [super vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_vector_space).

$^2$ One may show that kets in the image ${\rm Im}(\hat{Q})$ always have zero norm.